counting insider buying from openinsider in google sheets
I found this solution on StackOverflow:
ImportXML function in Google Sheets - count unique results for applied filters but its unfortunately not working.

It is adding all negative and positive insider transactions up and makes no difference between insider buying and selling.
if the same person makes two different insider buys it counts them as one 

Does anyone know how to fix this formula ? Thank you!
I tried to fix the formula in several ways

Please do NOT share images as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as a plain text table to the question. Click here to create a markdown table, which is easier to copy/paste as well. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example, also, provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

but its unfortunately not working. Please show formula(s) used to display the information in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to fix this formula ? Please show the outcome that you are trying to achieve. if the same person makes two different insider buys it counts them as one Please provide an example. I tried to fix the formula in several ways TBH, I don't understand either the problem or the outcome that you are trying to achieve. It seems to be assumed that a user will intuitively understand the problem & outcome; but this needs to be explained in detail.

@4thAnd1 The screen shot is not "data" per se but the outcome of two IMPORTHTML formulas. They are too long to include here. The OP should edit the question to include the formulas AND explain how they relate to the "problem".

Sorry for the bad explanation and sorry for your comments and help. I put the spreadsheets and this link. and try to explain a bit. I search at openinsider.com a stockticker "A2" in this case "ACIC" and see the insider buying and selling. I want to make a formula in google sheets that imports the the data from this side and gives me the sum of all insider buying of the last 180 days and the number of insider buying the last 180 days.

Unfortunately the formula is adding up the buying and selling and doesnt only look for buying. In the Example you can see (I added some comments in the sheet) that the number: should be 90,928 but is 1,190,080. Trying to filter to "P-Purchase" doent work because it shows "No Purchase" which is obviously wrong. In the end I would like to have a formula in one cell that adds up only all "P-Purchase" in Amount Dollar in the last 180 days and another formula in all "P-Purchase" in numbers (How many "P-Purchase" trades have been made the last 180 days. Thank you in advance!

1) The ticker included in your question is HRTG. This should be the example used in your spreadsheet. 2) may I respectfully suggest that the problem that you are having is unrelated to IMPORTHTML but rather it concerns the range of options that Openinsider allows.

Getting only the value of "Buy" on Openinsider
After experimenting things, I found out that the problem may be because of the wrong filter performed back in Openinsider. I performed a new filter back in Openinsider website and managed to get the expected result. You might have just forgotten to click the search button on Openinsider site when you input the filter values.
Regarding your concern about the other QUERY returning "No Purchase" I suggest that you post it as another question as you might encounter issues chaining it to the concern addressed by this answer.
Sample output

References: IMPORTHTML

I agree with your conclusions but this makes me think that the question is off-topic because it is not a programming issue; it reflects the OP's lack of understanding of the Openinsider options.
